# Fault domain of Virtual Machines in an availability set

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I read the following in the *AZURE214x Azure Fundamentals* openedx course:

> Each virtual machine in an availability set is placed in one update
>   domain and two fault domains.

I don't understand why a VM in an availabilty set is placed in **two** fault domains? I mean a VM can only sit in one fault domain or am I wrong? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each virtual machine in an availability set is placed in one update
>   domain and two fault domains.

No, this is wrong.

Each virtual machine in your availability set is assigned an update domain and a fault domain by the underlying Azure platform.

Also, you could refer to [Mistake in Module3, Review question 2 (AZURE202x Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines)](https://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/tcml/forum/tcml_mat-course_38202/mistake-in-module3-review-question-2-azure202x/c3acc4ea-e2d8-4e3d-964c-21214317fc7d?auth=1).

Answer (score 1):

I guess its just a wording thing, VM cannot be in 2 fault domains at the same time.

"Each virtual machine in your availability set is assigned an update domain and a fault domain by the underlying Azure platform."

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-manage-availability